# Code to find the hull of a list of ROC curves (upper and lower limits of the set of curves)

Tags: r, confidence-interval, roc

I have made code that computes the two lines I am asking for in the question, as shown in the image below (desired lines are in red).

**EDIT : This is the expected graph using my snippet to generate the ROC curves (atleast I'm pretty sure this is right) :**

[image: Hull of set of ROC curves]

The problem is that said code is very very ugly (too long to even post here) and the process I came up with seems extremely tedious to me. Yet I can't seem to come up with anything better.

Here is a quick snippet to produce an input list of ROC curves

```
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)

simple_roc <- function(labels, scores){
  labels <- labels[order(scores, decreasing=TRUE)]
  return(rbind(c(0,0,0),data.frame(TPR=cumsum(labels)/sum(labels), FPR=cumsum(!labels)/sum(!labels), labels)))
}

diab_data=rbind(data.frame(Pima.tr),data.frame(Pima.te))

roc_curves_list_logisitic=list()

for (k in 1:100) {

  #Set a fixed seed for reproducibility
  set.seed(k)

  # sampled_rows <- createDataPartition(diab_data$type, p = .7, list = FALSE)

  sampled_rows <- sample(1:nrow(diab_data), size=floor(0.7*nrow(diab_data)))

  diab_data_train=diab_data[sampled_rows,]
  diab_data_test=diab_data[-sampled_rows,]
  diab_data_train[,1:7]=scale(diab_data_train[,1:7])
  diab_data_test[,1:7]=scale(diab_data_test[,1:7])

  diab_data_train[,"type"]=as.numeric(as.character(recode_factor(diab_data_train[,"type"],`Yes` = "1", `No` = "0")))

  diab_data_test[,"type"]=as.numeric(as.character(recode_factor(diab_data_test[,"type"],`Yes` = "1", `No` = "0")))


  logistic_model_simple=glm(data=diab_data_train,as.formula(paste(colnames(diab_data_train)[8], "~",
                                                                  paste(colnames(diab_data_train)[-8], collapse = "+"),
                                                                  sep = "")),family=binomial(link = "logit"))

  roc_curves_list_logisitic[[k]]=simple_roc(diab_data_test[,"type"], 
                                            ifelse(predict(logistic_model_simple,diab_data_test,type='response')>0.5,1,0))

}
```

I am now asking for help, in case anyone has a "beautiful" solution to produce the two red lines in this graph (in ggplot2) using the list of ROC curves I provided as input.

Preferably I would like to end up with two dataframes `lower_bound_roc_curves` and `upper_bound_roc_curves` containing the necessary values to plot the two lines seperately if I need them.

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT 2 :@denis Here are some parts I think your code gets wrong :**

[image: First plot dennis]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution with `data.table` and `zoo`. The first step is to have a common FPR between all your curves. It is to be able to plot the maximum and the minimum of all curve. To do so:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

FPRlist <- unique(rbindlist(lapply(roc_curves_list_logisitic,function(ROC){
  rccurve <- as.data.table(ROC)
  rccurve[,.(FPR = FPR)]
})))
```

I create a table  `FPRlist` containing all the FPR existing in all your curves. I will after merge each curve with this table containing all FPR, and use na.locf to complete the missing values.
I use rbindlist to make one table, with an ID for each ROC curve

```
results <- rbindlist(lapply(seq(roc_curves_list_logisitic),function(idx){
  rccurve <- as.data.table(roc_curves_list_logisitic[[idx]])
  rccurve <- merge(FPRlist,rccurve,all = T)
  rccurve[,TPR := na.locf(TPR,na.rm = F)] # I complete the values
  rccurve[,ID := idx] # I create an ID
  rccurve
}))
```

I then calculate the max and min across all ID (all ROC curve) for each FPR step

```
resultmax <- results[,.(TPR = max(TPR)),by = FPR]
resultmin <- results[,.(TPR = min(TPR)),by = FPR]
```

And plot it the same way you plot it

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = results,aes(FPR,TPR,color = as.factor(ID)))+
  theme_light() %+replace% theme(legend.position = "none")+
  geom_line(data = resultmax,aes(FPR,TPR),color = "red",size = 1)+
  geom_line(data = resultmin,aes(FPR,TPR),color = "red",size = 1)
```

[image]

I let the `dplyr` translation to `dplyr` users, because I am not used to.

## Edit

I modified my plot to make a comparison with the plot of just all raw ROC curves without any merge nor `na.locf`. One can see that the red lines I propose do follow the max and the min of all curves. The second plot is obtained as follow:

```
results2 <- rbindlist(lapply(seq(roc_curves_list_logisitic),function(idx){
  rccurve <- as.data.table(roc_curves_list_logisitic[[idx]])
  rccurve[,ID := idx] # I create an ID
  rccurve
}))

p2 <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = results2,aes(FPR,TPR,color = as.factor(ID)))+
  theme_light() %+replace% theme(legend.position = "none")
```

It just plots all the ROC curves contained in the list provided in the OS question. The two column plot is obtained with `multiplot` function (see [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/))

Comment: Hey denisn thank you for your quick answer

Sadly I believe that I can't accept it since I think it doesn't give the desired result. Unless I'm missing something the red lines do not correspond to the hull everywhere. I will post the expected result given with the ROC curves from my snippet in my question. You'll see that your red lines and mine are different. 

Nevertheless, thanks for the code!

Comment: I could try to work for your answer to get to the desired results. The function you use are definetely helpful and interesting to me since I don't have much/no experience with data.table/zoo

Comment: @JoelH I don't actually see a difference between your graph and mine, appart for the 0,0 point. Could you describe what you actually want ? I seemed to me that you wanted the maximum and minimum of all roc curve, and my code actually gives this result. The upper curve has a non zero TPR for FPR = 0 because one of your ROC curve has the value TPR = 0.21 for FPR = 0. The actual maximum value of all you cruve soesn't start at 0 in your example.

Comment: I made an edit to my initial question showing parts of your red lines I think are wrong (there are more I believe!). I was not talking about the part where FPR=0.

Comment: @JoelH I made an edit also. I don't think I am wrong, I think you are not using the data you provide for your graph. See my graph, were I plot the raw data without the red line. One can clearly see the part you thing are wrong do appear in your data you provide but not in your graph. I provide the code for the plot of the second graph.

Comment: Oh, I am wrong indeed! I must apologize I had overseen something in my definition of my seeds in my script (which then caused my curves to be different). I will thus accept your answer, thank you very much for your help!